# Skip init for singleton object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, init

I have a singleton implemented in my app, but I've run into a problem when I switch between view controllers.

My app starts in one view controller, MainMenu, then switches to the Game view controller when the menu selection is made.  I have a singleton class in the Game VC that is the object manager (called World) for the game.  It loads content based on the menu selection in MainMenu.  I can load up and quit back to the MainMenu VC fine.  Singleton works fine.  When I select from the MainMenu again (going from MainMenu VC to Game VC), my app crashes cause of an NSAssert to prevent the singleton World from allocating a second time, which is intentional.

How can I switch back to the Game VC without it trying to reinitialize my singleton?

Essentially, I want to skip the `[[world alloc] init]` line in my Game VC's init method.  I can't figure out how to do this properly... it would need to be able to be handled the first time (when World doesn't exist) or any subsequent time (when World already exists as a singleton).  I've tried `if (!world)` and that doesn't work.

This also begs the question... did I implement my singleton in the right place?  Should I perhaps put it in the MainMenu instead?  I just want to avoid it trying to reinitialize / reallocate the singleton when I switch between the two VCs.

If this helps, I'm exiting the Game VC by using `[self.view removeFromSuperview];`  Should I do it a different way?

Comment: A singleton doesn't need to be implemented/stored anywhere, because it is a singleton. An alternative is to store as a normal class on the AppDelegate, which is already a singleton. But then you have to write `(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].world` for access.

Comment: It seems to me that it does matter where you implement it, depending on your design... I was messing around and when I moved the singleton to my MainMenu view controller, it solved my problem since the MainMenu VC only initializes once in my app (the custom init method in my Game VC is called every time I switch to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this by indeed moving the singleton initialization up into the MainMenu view controller as I was thinking.  In my design, `init` for that VC is only called once upon app startup, whereas the custom `init` method in my Game VC gets called each time I switch to it.

Not sure if that's the optimal design I should be using, but it works for now.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you'd like to know how to create a Singleton class? A common way in recent times is to use grand-central-dispatch, as follows:

```
+ (MyViewController*)shared
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static MyViewController* instance;

    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
    {
        instance = [[[self class] alloc] init];
    });
    return instance;
}
```

you can then access the instance with:

```
[MyViewController shared];
```

Before grand-central-dispatch, the technique was to put a static instance on the class and check if it's nil when calling the shared accessor. And the accessor would need to be wrapped with @synchronized(self) to ensure thread-safety. The GCD way has been shown to perform a little better.

Having said that, I recommend that you use singletons with volition. Do some research on why they're considered an anti-pattern, and investigate dependency injection as an alternative.

**Dependency Injection vs Singletons**

The problem with singletons is that they can lead to tight coupling. Let's say you're building an airline booking system. Your booking controller might use an:

```
id<FlightsClient>
```

A common way to obtain it within the controller would be as follows:

```
_flightsClient = [FlightsClient sharedInstance];
```

In order to test a class using the singleton, you now have to test the singleton at the same time, and this can get tricky, especially as your application gets more complex. Imagine testing Class A, depends on Class B, depends on Class C, depends on .... Not much fun!

An alternative is to use dependency injection, which simply means to pass the booking client to the booking controller using an initializer or property setter. You can do this manually or use a library for it. If you do it manually its still OK to declare the singleton, although arguably you will not need to as the top-level assembly class can retain the instance.

By using this alternative approach to singletons, classes will have loose coupling, and will be easy to test and maintain. (And with Dependency Injection, you'll have an equally fancy name ;) )

I wrote a dependency injection library, based on Spring: https://github.com/jasperblues/spring-objective-c

Comment: Note that the `dispatch_once` approach also is thread-safe -- it won't be possible for two threads to access the instance, see that it is nil, and each try to initialize it.

Comment: @MaxGabriel - Very good point! I think I'll add that to the main answer. . . . done!

Comment: An alternative thread safe approach without GCD is to set a static field from the +initialize method. That makes the if thread safe without @synchronized because +initialize is called just once by the runtime before the class receives any other message.

Comment: No, I know how to implement a singleton class.  My problem was that I had it in the wrong place in my design.  To be honest, I'm not sure how I would design my app without using a singleton.

Comment: Ah, ok. I'm updating the answer with more info.

Comment: @JasperBlues Thanks for the info on Dependency Injection, though.  That's not something I'm familiar with but I'll read up on it.